# Problem with Youtube Video Downloader Tkinter in pycharm

Tags: python, tkinter, pytube

I attempted to make a Youtube video downloader through Pycharm. All is functional, but when I try to download any video whatsoever, i get this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\PycharmProjects\YoutubeVideoDownloader\main.py", line 23, in Downloader
    url = YouTube(str(link.get()))
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in prefetch
    self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 36, in get
    return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 557, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 749, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone
```

i am very confused as to what is causing this issue, and would really appreciate it if someone could help with this since im relatively new to python and coding in general.

Here below is the source code for the downloader.

```
from tkinter import *
import pytube
from pytube import YouTube

# Setting Window Resolution and App Title
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title('Youtube Video Downloader')

# SETTING THE FONT OF THE TEXT IN SAID WINDOW
Label(root, text='Youtube Video Downloader', font='arial 20 bold').pack()

# Variable that stores YouTube link that you input
link = StringVar()
#
Label(root, text='Paste link here:', font='arial 15 bold').place(x=160, y=60)
link_enter = Entry(root, width=70, textvariable=link).place(x=32, y=90)


#
def Downloader():
    url = YouTube(str(link.get()))
    video = url.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    video.download()
    Label(root, text='DOWNLOADED', font='arial 15').place(x=180, y=210)

#
Button(root, text='DOWNLOAD', font='arial 15 bold', bg='pale violet red', padx=2, command=Downloader).place(x=180, y=150)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: From what I can see, `HTTP Error 410` means that the requested file is no longer there.

Comment: thats weird because i specifically tried out multiple links and they are all still public on youtube

Comment: Ok. So I tried one link and it works just fine. I'm running Python Python 3.6.5 on Windows 10 from IDLE. Can there be a problem with pycharm? Other than that I see no obvious problem source where I differ from you.

Comment: huh, could it be that since im using python 3.10 that it runs into this issue then? Weird.

Comment: Checking the documentation it says: "Pytube requires an installation of Python 3.6 or greater"

Comment: Worked for me. Python3.12.0a5

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade `pytube`

This worked for me:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```